# Django many to one operations

Tags: python, django

I have two tables in my model as shown  below:

```
class grade(models.Model):
    # Class of student
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique = True)

class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

As it can be seen the grade is common in both the tables.
I can access these two tables separately using the urls '/grade' for first table and '/name' for second.
What I am looking for is a new table which takes both the tables and give something like below (with an example):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/homqg.png)

And I want to this so that I can perform the following functions:
post,delete /grade/{grade_value}/name/{name_value}

Also,
get /grade/{grade_value}

so that I can get the information about all the students of that grad value.

I know I am required to use many to one and I have read the documentation as well, have tried a few times but wasn't successful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it :

models.py:

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()

class Third(models.Model):
    grade = models.OneToOneField(grade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    stds = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def serialize(students):
    s_list = []
    fields = ['name', 'grade', 'rollno']
    for student in students:
        s_list.append(model_to_dict(student, fields=fields))
    return s_list

def index(request):         
    g1 = Grade.objects.get(grade='9')
    g2 = Grade.objects.get(grade='10')
    students = Student.objects.filter(grade=g1) 
    Third.objects.create(grade=g1, stds=serialize(students))
    students = Student.objects.filter(grade=g2) 
    Third.objects.create(grade=g2, stds=serialize(students))    
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

By convention, class names should start with a capital letter.

References:

- [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)
- [ManyToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
- [model_to_dict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/models/)

Comment: @Shubhankar Does that help ? :)

Comment: Hey Ahtisham, Thanks for the reply. It does make sense. I implemented your recommendation, just modified the serialzer and views. I have added it in the edit, if you'd like to see. Though when I try to delete an entry, it cannot. Also, I am not sure if I want to delete/update an entry should I do in the first two models or the third model, so that it deletes everything.

Comment: Well deleting should be simply `Grade.objects.get(pk=1).delete()` will delete Grade instance/object of pk 1 and all of its related instances in `Student` and `Third` model.

Comment: My bad, the delete works but I get an integrity error just on reloading. I think it is because of .create function in the index,because when I reload it; it tries to recreate with the same grade and gives me an integrity error. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Set the attribute `grade` of your model `Student` as a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to the model `Grade`.

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    grade = models.IntegerField()

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
    rollno = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I do this how can I declare an instance of grade to be accepted in student, Earlier I was just saying gradeID=request.data["gradeID"] for both the models. Now I cannot do this in class student